# Need VBA code to search for data in a sheet and print the selected data in one page

Tags: vba, excel

I need to find various data in a sheet and select those data and print the selected data to printout and all data to be printed in one page. I tried with this code but something is wrong:

```
Sub Selection()
Dim varRow As String

For i = 1 To Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
If Range("A" & i).Value = "M655" Or Range("A" & i).Value = "Equity Fund" Then
    If Trim(varRow) <> "" Then
    varRow = varRow & "," & i & ":" & i
    Else
    varRow = varRow & i & ":" & i
    End If
End If
Next i

Range(varRow).Select


Selection.PrintOut
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
    .PrintTitleRows = "$3:$3"
    .PrintTitleColumns = "$B:$B"
    .Orientation = xlLandscape
    .Zoom = False
    .FitToPagesWide = 1
    .FitToPagesTall = 1

End with
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

One issue is that after you loop through the cells, varRow is a string of "M655" and "Equity Fund" separated by commas. You then try to use that string as an argument for a range which is invalid. If you are trying to build a a string of range addresses ("a1", "a2", etc) try using the .AddressLocal property. Also, you use .PrintOut prior to setting the print settings. Try putting that line after you set the page setup settings to have them take effect.